# Patching around a pipe exit in stucco wall

Tags: caulking, stucco

We just purchased a home and the seller hired a handyperson to run a pipe for the hot water heater pressure release. They ran a copper pipe down...at the bottom there's an elbow that's connected to another pipe that exits through a hole they drilled to the outside.  The outside of our house has stucco. What do I do to seal the gap around the copper pipe?  Do I just use some caulk?  I basically want to prevent rain water from leaking into the gap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A caulk rated for outdoor use should be just fine for this sealing job. If there is any fine particulate in the area left over from drilling through the stucco do brush or blow it away before applying the caulk.